# maven cyclic dependency resolution

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Can anyone please help to resolve this cyclic dependency error within my application.

Here is my case: I have 2 classes which need to communicate with each other based on decider value but those 2 classes stay in different modules If I try to add dependency among those that lead to Cyclic Dependency error.

A Sample functionality I'm planning would be similar to this

```
class A {
    void funA() {
        System.out.print("Module A");
    }

    void Validate() {
        boolean decider = true; // if true indicates belongs to Class A else B
        if (decider) {
            funA();
        } else {
            B b = new B();
            b.funB();
        }
    }

    private class B {
        void funB() {
            System.out.print("Module B");
        }

        void Validate() {
            boolean decider = false;// if true indicates belongs to Class A else B
            if (decider) {
                funB();
            } else {
                A a = new A();
                a.funA();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***ClassA*** stays within ***ModuleA*** and ***ClassB*** stays within ***ModuleB***, How can i achieve above functionality even by creating a new module and moving common functionality

Comment: I tried to add another module with validate() code but even that leads to Cyclic dependency as ModuleC would need both funA(), funB() access and for funA() to communicate with moduleC needs its dependency

Comment: In brief, refactor your code and your module structure to avoid cyclic dependencies between modules.  The code seems so vague and unrealistic that it is hard for us to suggest how you should refactor

Comment: Do you really need to instantiate `B`  in `A`'s `validate()` (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

If a class `A` needs to instantiate a class `B` and `B` needs to instantiate a class `A` (meaning calling `new A()` etc.), than both classes have to be in the same module. So your construction is just not possible.

I guess, though, that your intended logic can be implemented, but it is unclear to me what you really want to achieve with your "decider" and your different calls.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code is not very realistic, it is difficult to suggest how you can refactor the code.

Here are some suggestions that hopefully can give you inspiration to deal with your real problem

### Approach 1: Put A and B in same module

You could pull `A` and `B` out as a common module.  So inter-reference between `A` and `B` is not a problem coz they are in same module.  Original `module_a` and `module_b` will both depends on the new `a_b_common` module (which contains `A` and `B`)

### Approach 2: Break dependency between A and B

Refactor your code so A and B does not depends on each other directly.  There are lots of way, here is just one example:

Have `Action` in a common module

```
interface Action {
    void perform();
}
```

Make A not depends on B anymore

```
class A {
    Action fallbackAction;  // setter etc

    void validate() {
        if xxxxx {
            funcA();
        } else {
            fallbackAction.perform();
        }
    }
}

// similar for B
```

With use of dependency injection, construct A and B by something like

```
A a = new A();
a.setFallbackAction(new Action(){ 
                      void perform() { new B().funcB(); }
                    } );
B b = new B();
b.setFallbackAction(new Action(){ 
                      void perform() { new A().funcA(); }
                    } );
```

(of course, you can even use lambda and functional interface in Java8 for above stuff. This just give you a high level idea)

Comment: Adrian, i even thought of Approach 2 but i have a small doubt in which module does the third code block lies (**construct A and B**)

Comment: Usually you have a "module" for your application (in which it perform DI etc.)